# What's Android database files structure

Tags: java, android, database, file, media

i'm trying to deal with Android since few weeks. And i'm now trying to access media databases files like photo, music, videos,settings,installed applications stored in the phone. What's these files paths?
I've already find contacts, bookmarks, sms files under "/data/data/com.android.providers" structure.
Can someone tell me the whole database structure?

Answer (score 1):

your databases are under /data/data/[your package name]/databases/[your database name] although you should usually not be trying to access these

### edit

adamcodes is right, corrected

Comment: /data/data/[your package name]/databases/[your database name]

Comment: Ok. I'm not trying to access my own application database. Assume i'm trying to backup the phone important files like music,videos,... So, I need these paths to copy .db files. Is that possible programmaticaly?